# XMLHttpRequest from Google App Engine app to other Google App engine app (different ports)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine

I'm attempting to make an XMLHttpRequest (i.e. $.ajax) from a google app engine application (front-end) to another google app engine app (back-end that returns JSON), however, when I try the call always fails ... probably because the user from the first application is not logged into the second application, I was wondering if some of you had the same issue and how is it possible to resolve it.

(GAE Java SDK)

Thanks

Comment: What is in the log of your back-end?

Answer (score 1):

If the two apps have different URLs, it might be related to this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Thanks dardo, but the Java app, is returning the correct header 
in this case:

resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: To solve  (same Origin Policy) you can use send the request to your front-end and have the request send to your hidden back-end.